# Folder with red and green arrows - what does this mean and why can't I see this in Files?

Tags: files, zfs, plex

Does anyone know what these arrows mean and why I cannot see this folder in "Files" as a selectable folder?  My media is loaded in my ZFS array here but I cannot see this folder to populate my Plex server.

[image]